# Move SSD into the same IOMMU group as the second GPU

Tags: nvme, iommu

I have a working Qemu configuration with GPU-pass-through. Now I would like to pass also a SSD to the quest. I have read that the pass-through-devices should be in the same group. The following script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s nullglob
for g in /sys/kernel/iommu_groups/*; do
    echo "IOMMU Group ${g##*/}:"
    for d in $g/devices/*; do
        echo -e "\t$(lspci -nns ${d##*/})"
    done
done
```

Shows that my GPU is in group 8, but the SSD is in group 9.

```
IOMMU Group 8:
        01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation TU117 [GeForce GTX 1650] [10de:1f82] (rev a1)
        01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:10fa] (rev a1)
IOMMU Group 9:
        02:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 500 Series Chipset USB 3.1 XHCI Controller [1022:43ee]
        02:00.1 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 500 Series Chipset SATA Controller [1022:43eb]
        02:00.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 500 Series Chipset Switch Upstream Port [1022:43e9]
        03:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43ea]
        03:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43ea]
        03:08.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43ea]
        03:09.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43ea]
        05:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller 980 [144d:a809]
        07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
```

How to move the SSD into group 8?

I used already `driverctl set-override 0000:05:00.0 vfio-pci` to change the driver from `nvme` to `vfio-pci`, but this does not change the IOMMU group.

Answer (score 1):

An IOMMU group is the smallest group of PCI devices that can be passed through as "unit". It's a hardware property, and looking at your chipset, I don't think you will be able to reconfigure that hardware.

So, you can't take something out of a group – otherwise it'd be a group of its own.

Thus, you would have to pass through your Group 9. That looks unlikely to work.

Comment: [This](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#Isolating_the_GPU) explains how to isolate the GPU, which means changing the groups, which means they are not fixed. I want to do the same with the SSD.

Comment: you need to bind every device in that group to vfio-pci pseudodriver. You're in the situation [that your nvme is not in an isolated PCIe slot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#Plugging_your_guest_GPU_in_an_unisolated_CPU-based_PCIe_slot) and would have to re-assign the whole group. OR go through rather adventurous paths, which I'm really not convinced will take you anywhere sensible.

Comment: Does this mean, that SSD pass-through is not possible in general?

Comment: no. Definitely not what I said.